# One block of pulley system collides with the ground

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

**Question:-**

[image]

**My attempt:**
Since the P block is given a velocity v in the downward direction, the Q block will move in the opposite direction(upwards) with the same velocity v. When the P block collides with the ground, the Q block will have to stop as well and right after that instant P block will move rebound and move upwards and Q downwards. So the answer has to be (c). But the book says that the answer is (a). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

As Q had upward motion with velocity v, it keeps on moving up due to inertia of motion at that instant when P had striked and rebounded.May be due to elastic collision P moves up with v velocity.